# How to flush string which is in structure?

Tags: c, pointers, buffer, structure, flush

My structure:

```
struct Data{
   char buffer[MAX_BUFF];
   int bufferPos;
};
```

How I execute function `searchFile`:

```
searchFile(outFile, logFile, category, keyword, srcName, &dat);
```

In function `searchFile` I would like to do something like `fflush(dat->buffer)`. Unfortunately, this gives me an error. I also tried `str(dat->buffer, "")` and `dat->buffer[0] = '\0'`, but this does not seem to clear out my string `dat.buffer`. Any ideas?

Full code: http://pastebin.com/aHWPLqPx

Comment: What do you mean by "flush" in this context? Do you want to write zeros to the buffer (`memset` or `bzero`)?

Comment: I save a string in dat.buffer. What i want to do, is completely delete that string from buffer, so that when I say printf("%s", dar.buffer) it would print out nothing.

Comment: You last example should have accomplished the that, though it would have left most (all but the first `char`) of the string still present in the memory occupied by `dat->buffer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to remove any meaningful data from the buffer, you would overwrite the whole thing with zeros and reset `bufferPos`.

Something like

```
memset(dat->buffer,0,MAX_BUFF);
dat->bufferPos=0;
```